# TCPDF and certains SVG not rendering correctly

Tags: php, svg, tcpdf

I'm trying TCPDF and the example 058 on my php server (https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_058/).
The example itself works great. I downloaded others SVG files to try if everything is correct, but some of them don't render correctly, or are completely broken.

In the example 058 code I changed 2 things :
1) the svg file path
2) the height and width to 100 and 100

Here is one of the broken SVG rendering i got, with the Firefox logo found on wikipedia :
[On the left, the SVG rendered in Chrome, on the right, the pdf with Firefox logo inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqKPm.jpg)

I'm using PHP 7.1.x and TCPDF 6.2.25. Is it a bug in TCPDF or an error in the SVG file ?

Comment: Why not share your code here instead of describing what you have done?

Comment: This is a common complaint.  Most likely, your issues are due to deficiencies in the SVG parser/converter in TCPDF.  I think the best you can really do is file a bug with TCPDF.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I didn't share code because this is exactly the same code as example 058 (see 1st link). I changed line 80 : $pdf->ImageSVG($file='images/Mozilla_Firefox_logo_2013.svg', $x=30, $y=100, $w=100, $h=100, $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=false);
I will see directly with TCPDF.

Comment: I answered a similar question not too long ago. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51109754/395384 - It is almost assuredly a limitation of TCPDF. Your best bet is to rasterize it. Either beforehand or with `setRasterizeVectorImages`

Comment: Thank you @EPB, I think I have no choise but do rasterization

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying to switch to the [mPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) library. I was having numerous issues with the TCPDF library myself, and most of them have been resolved by switching to the mPDF library.

The best way to use it, I've found is to generate an HTML document, including your svg image resources. It renders all the strange unicode characters I have to use for this project, and has not given me nearly as many placement or rendering issues. It's also being actively maintained. TCPDF hasn't been updated from what I can tell since 2011.

```
$mPdf = new Mpdf();
```

For example:

```
$html .= sprintf('<div id="svgPlot" style="position: fixed; top: %smm;">', $y);
$html .= '<svg> (blob of svg text) </svg>';
$html .= '</div>';
```

You can also use them in the html document as follows:

```
        $this->html .= sprintf('<div id="logo" style="left: -9mm; top: %smm; height:45mm; position: fixed;">', strval((int)$y + 1));
        $this->html .= sprintf('<img src="%s" alt="LOGO">', $logo); // $logo is resource location on your server for SVG logo file.
        $this->html .= '</div>';
```

To then complete the write you would use:

```
$mPdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

Then:

```
$mPdf->Output($localFileName, 'D');
```